# How to properly store lambda functions in a tuple and call them?

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm trying to create a class that can store functions in a member tuple. But when trying to put lambdas inside of an object's tuple (through function pointers) I'm getting a error. Please explain, what I'm doing wrong and what is the proper way of releasing this idea. I think there should be an elegant and stylistically correct general solution (in terms of functional programming patterns) to avoid boilerplate code in class description, objects creation and filling them with functions.

```
#include <functional>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

template<typename... ArgTypes> 
class MyClass {
public:
    //boolean function of some argument
    template<typename Type> using Func = bool(Type const &);

    //type for a tuple of pointers to templated boolean functions
    template<typename... Types> using TupleOfFunctions = typename std::tuple<Func<Types>*...>;
    
    //the tuple
    TupleOfFunctions<ArgTypes...> _tuple;
    
    //constructor
    MyClass(TupleOfFunctions<ArgTypes...> t) : _tuple(t) {  
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    MyClass<int, std::string> M({
        [](int &arg) { return arg > 0; },
        [](std::string &arg) { return arg == "abc"; }
    });
    
    std::cout << (*std::get<0>(M._tuple))(1);
    std::cout << (*std::get<1>(M._tuple))("xyz");
    
    return 0;
}
```

The error I get is

```
./test.cpp:26:3: error: no matching function for call to 'MyClass<int, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >::MyClass(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)'
   26 |  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```cpp
template<typename Type> using Func = bool(Type const &);
```

This line suggested functions taking in `const` type arguments. However:

```cpp
[](int &arg) { return arg > 0; },
[](std::string &arg) { return arg == "abc"; }
```

These two lines suggested non-const arguments.

Either remove the `const` from the first line, or add `const` to the second two should solve it.

---

> Could you, however, suggest some ideas of redesigning the class so that the boilerplate code of repeated explicit declaration of these types (in class template specification and lambda function arguments) can be avoided?

Part of the point of having lambda is anonymous function type. Actually trying to deduce a type of them, like what you did, was kind of going backward.

One way I would suggest to do this would be:

```cpp
template<typename ... Lambdas> 
class MyClass {
public:
    std::tuple<Lambdas...> _tuple;
    
    MyClass(Lambdas ... args) : _tuple(std::make_tuple(args ...)) {  
    }
};
```

Now you can use it like:

```cpp
MyClass M(
    [](const int &arg) { return arg > 0; },
    [](const std::string &arg) { return arg == "abc"; }
);
```

---

Alternatively, you might be interested in a variant/visit pattern: https://godbolt.org/z/5Pdn1Ynqe

Comment: thanks for your reply. Yes, I realized that the problem was a mismatch between types of the arguments in the templated function and in lambda functions. Writing equivalent types allowed the code to be compiled. Could you, however, suggest some ideas of redesigning the class so that the boilerplate code of repeated explicit declaration of these types (in class template specification and lambda function arguments) can be avoided? I want something like:

Comment: `MyClass<int, std::string, bool, float> M({[]() { return  arg == 10; }, []() { return  arg == "abc"; }, []() { return !arg; }, []() { return  arg < 10.0f; }});`

Comment: @layer19 I've edited my answer, hope it would help.

Comment: @layer19 Or maybe this is all you needed: https://godbolt.org/z/xE6o6T7ec

Answer (score 0):

A braced-init-list, like {}, does not actually have a type. In the context of template deduction, you can only use them in certain cases - when deducing against initializer_list (where T is a function template parameter) or when the corresponding parameter is already deduced by something else. In this case, neither of those two things is true - so the compiler cannot figure out what ...ArgTypes is supposed to be.

I think you should use `std::make_tuple` and store as lambda as function pointer.

[Live example](https://onlinegdb.com/QjjsNDjik)

Comment: thanks for your reply. Your suggestions on using std::make_tuple seem reasonable, however, as @Ranoiaetep pointed out, with the correct writing of equivalent types of passed arguments, the code will compile even if you use braced-init-list. Could you please also suggest some ideas of redesigning the class to incapsulate types of arguments passed to lambda functions inside the class itself so that the boilerplate code in the object initialization could be avoided?